# Function to disable jQuery preloader if page is already cached

Tags: jquery, preloader

I am using a [jQuery preloader](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/) for my images and I was wondering if it is possible to check if a page is already cached in a users browser before running the loader, is this possible?

The plugin runs on dom load with a function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").queryLoader2();
});
```

Could I write something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!page_cached) {
        $("body").queryLoader2();
    }
    else {
        //do nothing
        return false;
    }
});
```

Appreciate your responses, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a head request via ajax and if it returns 304 instead of 200, it would mean its there in the cache. Something in javascript would be like:

```
function isInCache(url)
{
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('HEAD', url, false);
  http.send();
  return http.status;
}
//then
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (isInCache(your_page_url) != "304") {
        $("body").queryLoader2();
    }
    else {
        //do nothing
        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've tried it and it seems to work, i'm currently looking into self caching my site w/ js.

Comment: My problem is I'm using CSS3Pie for my pure CSS3 elements and I'm trying to cut down on the time it takes IE to render the elements, the preloader works fine, but I'd rather not have return users wait if the site is already cached.  Any suggestions as to where to look into self caching?